# A small but tricky derivation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the dimensionless differential equation
$$
\frac{\text{d}^2\phi(s)}{\text{d}s^2} = \sinh(\phi(s)).
$$
Apparently, I should be able to derive that
$$
\frac{\text{d}\phi(s)}{\text{d}s} = \pm 2 \sinh(\phi(s)/2),
$$
by multiplying the former equation by $\phi'(s)$ and using the boundary condition $\phi(\infty)=0$.

I noted that $\frac{\text{d} }{\text{d}s} (\phi'(s))^2 = 2 \phi'\phi''$, so I can write the LHS as a total derivative, but I do not know what to do with the RHS. I suppose I should perform some partial integration, but I don't really know which one. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Once multiplied, the RHS becomes $\left(\operatorname{cosh}(\phi)\right)'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
2\phi'(s)\phi''(s) = 2\phi'(s)\sinh(\phi(s))\ .
$$
$$
[(\phi'(s))^2]' = 2[\cosh(\phi(s))]' .
$$
$$
\phi'(s) = \pm\sqrt{4\frac{\cosh(\phi(s))-1}{2}}=\pm2\sqrt{\frac{\cosh(\phi(s))-1}{2}}= \pm2\sinh\left(\frac{\phi(s)}{2}\right).
$$
using $2\sinh^2(x)=\cosh(2x)-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $\phi'(s)$ gives you

$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{ds}(\phi'(s)^2) = \phi'(s)sinh(\phi(s)) = \frac{d}{ds}cosh(\phi(s))$